# debian stretch wifi not working - iwlwifi installs but doesn't load correctly

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, firmware, iwlwifi

After upgrading debian jessie to stretch my wifi didn't work anymore (Toshiba Kira book). The laptop uses an Intel Wireless 7265 which [is supported by iwlwifi](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi).

So I downloaded the .deb files as linked [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch06s04.html.en) and did the following:

```
dpkg - i firmware-iwlwifi_0.43_all.deb
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

However, even after rebooting, the wifi doesn't show up... `iwconfig` says that there is no wireless extension.... the `dpkg` command worked and the iwlwifi module is installed.

`dmesg | grep wifi` tells me a couple of times:

```
firmware failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-18.u code with error (-2)

Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.u code failed with error -2
```

The numbers after the second dash go from 13 to 18.

The wifi did work before I upgraded to stretch so it should in principle be supported. How can I get it to work?

**Edit**

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` outputs:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: please edit and add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving [`iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode) to `/lib/firmware`, and if that fixes things, run `reportbug firmware-iwlwifi` and request an updated package.